# Locking rotation around Z axis in mobile orientation panorama view with threeJS

Tags: mobile, three.js, orientation, quaternions, panoramas

I need your help with ThreeJS, panorama view and Quaternions.

For mobile device orientation panorama view, in a page like this one:
https://richtr.github.io/Full-Tilt/examples/vr_test.html
how would you go about locking the view when rotating around the Z axis (between the use and the middle of the screen), like the way this video does:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLbsGxdAPhjv_tgCNWGaGvSnlIMZNkmnrM&t=10&v=ClAuhgFQpLo

Please watch on mobile.

Thanks!
Sa'ar